# Trouble installing from USB stick

Tags: boot

I get the following error message while trying to install UBUNTU 12.10 from USB stick:

```
"ERROR: No configuration file found
No DEFAULT or UI cnfiguration directive found!
boot:"
```

Can you suggest solution?

Answer (score 1):

which tool you used to burn iso on the usb? I suggest using pendrive for burning linux images on USb sticks. Manual how to do so is located on the official ubuntu website http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows 
Seems like some config files missing due to wrong iso burning.